# Can we use multiple second-level domains with multitenancy?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I have implemented the simplest example using the [Spatie docs for multitenancy](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/introduction), that is working perfectly fine. Now, I intend to use multiple second-level domains for each tenant I have.

For example; I have 2 tenants `company-a` and `company-b` and they are being served at `company-a.localhost` and `company-b.localhost`, now what I want is that when I visit `company-a.admin.localhost`, it should tell me **COMPANY-A ADMIN** and If I visit `company-a.employee.localhost`, it should tell me **COMPANY-A EMPLOYEE**.

I have tried using `subdomain` on routes in `RouteServiceProvider` like the following:

```
           Route::middleware('web')
                ->group(base_path('routes/security.php'));

           Route::domain($this->baseDomain('admin'))
                ->middleware('web')
                ->name('admin.')
                ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));

           Route::domain($this->baseDomain('employee'))
                ->middleware('web')
                ->name('employee.')
                ->group(base_path('routes/employee.php'));

           private function baseDomain(string $subdomain = ''): string
           {
             if (strlen($subdomain) > 0) {
                $subdomain = "{$subdomain}.";
              }
             return $subdomain . config('app.base_domain');
           }
```

Without subdomain, it works fine, but the routes with second-level domain, it falls to base level domain route and does not get the current tenant.
What am I missing here? Is this even possible to implement.

Thankyou.

Comment: Can you share baseDomain function? and also how to serve at company-a.localhost and company-b.localhost

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur question edited

Comment: `php artisan serve` is by default serving the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by using some checks, in `RouteServiceProvider`, I have not used the actual `domain` function on `Route` like we do normally i.e. `Route::domain('foo.bar')`. The reason was that, the `Spatie` package use a kind of middleware `Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\DomainTenantFinder::class` which runs whenever we hit the domain with tenant `comapny-a.localhost`. And it gets the tenant from hostname i.e `comapny-a.localhost`.

```
    public function findForRequest(Request $request):?Tenant
    {
        $host = $request->getHost();
        return $this->getTenantModel()::whereDomain($host)->first();
    }
```

In my `RouteServiceProvide`:

```
     $this->routes(function () {
         $class = 'security';
         $middleware = 'web';
         if (Str::contains(request()->getHost(), 'admin')) {
             $class = 'admin';
         } elseif (Str::contains(request()->getHost(), 'employee')) {
             $class = 'employee';
         } elseif (Str::contains(request()->getHost(), 'api')) {
             $class = 'api';
             $middleware = 'api';
         }

         Route::middleware($middleware)
             ->name("$class.")
             ->group(base_path("routes/${class}.php"));
     });
```

As In my scenario, I had only these 2 kind of second-level domains and so, I just checked if this particular keyword exists in the hostname and choosing the file and middleware accordingly.

I also overrided the `DomainTenantFinder` class and in `multitenancy.php` config file:

```
    public function findForRequest(Request $request): ?Tenant
    {
        $host = $request->getHost();
        $host = str_replace('admin.', '', $host);
        $host = str_replace('employee.', '', $host);
        $host = str_replace('api.', '', $host);
        $tenant = $this->getTenantModel()::whereDomain($host)->first();
        if (empty($tenant)) {
            abort(404);
        }
        return $tenant;
    }
```

I have acheived the desired outcome, however, I have a security concern, specially in `RouteServiceProvider` logic. Thought??

Answer (score 0):

Take, for example, the route:

```
 Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')
   ->get('/foo/{param1}/{param2}',function(Router $router) {
       // do something with it
   });
```

The binding fields would be `['subdomain', 'param1', 'param2']`, and the compiled route would have it's regexes declared as

```
regex => "{^/foo/(?P<param1>[^/]++)/(?P<param2>[^/]++)$}sDu",
hostRegex => "{^(?P<subdomain>[^\.]++)\.example\.com$}sDiu"
```

Where `^(?P<subdomain>[^\.]++)\.` will explicitly stop capturing when finding a dot, in this case the delimiter between groups.

However, these regexes are overridable by using the `where` method. You could declare the above route as

```
 Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')
   ->get('/foo/{param1}/{param2}',function(Router $router) {
       // do something with it
   })->where('subdomain', '(.*)');
```

In the compiled route , the hostRegex would be now

```
 hostRegex => "{^(?P<subdomain>(?:.*))\.example\.com$}sDiu"
```

Meaning it will capture anything preceding `.example.com`. If you requested `company-a.admin.example.com`, `$subdomain` would be `company-a.admin`.

You could also declare a route with two binding fields in its domain:

```
 Route::domain('{subsubdomain}.{subdomain}.example.com')
   ->get('/foo/{param1}/{param2}',function(Router $router) {
       // do something with it
   });
```

Which might be more useful if you wanted subsubdomains to imply a hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I was looking to get the `baseDomain` on which the tenants are being served, the idea is that `DomainTenantFinder` will get the host that is in this is `company-a.admin.localhost` and regardless of whatever is written at place of `admin`, logic should determine `company-a.localhost` and get the matching `tenant`